# Batch file to generate n amount of folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

Hi I would like to create a batch file which makes n amount of folders and moves them to a specified dir. something like `make folders {00001-00009}` to put it bluntly. I don't want to manually put each number in and I would like to be able to exclude numbers as well.

so far I have tried this code below. I get the 5 folders made in C:\source\
and I am able to dictate how they are named to an extent, by changing `j=5` to whatever integer, however sometimes the file makes folders from 00256-003372 instead of what I specified. this happens when I change `j` to `j=256` and run the program.

```
echo off
cd C:\source\ :: I included this because for some reason folder 1 copied to root 
SET /a j=1
:floop
IF %j%==5 GOTO END 
md 00%j% 
cd 00%j% 
SET /a j=%j%+1 
cd C:\source\
GOTO FLOOP
:end
```

The other way I did this was to manually input each number in a .bat file such as below. which works fine but I have to make a line for each folder.

```
md C:\Device_Numbers_Folder\00001
md C:\Device_Numbers_Folder\00002
```

P.S I named the dir file `source` because I am running a bunch of .bat files with `CALL` and this is the source part.

Comment: The loop will only stop once j = 5. But if j is larger than 5 then it has to wait until the variable overflows, return to 0 then moves to 5 until the loop will stop which will create a tonne of extra folders. try changing "IF %j%==5 GOTO END" to "IF %j%==256 GOTO END"

Comment: I gave it a bash but it did not work for me. My understanding of this code is that in "IF %j%==5 GOTO END"

Comment: 5 is the amount of files which are formed. previously i had tried to start from 256 and add files so my output should have been File256, File257...File260.

Comment: I have however found something else. If i change   "SET /a j=5"  too 256 and   "IF %j%==5 GOTO END" to 260 I get what I want... still need to figure out how to exclude and how to number like {256-300}

Comment: All "IF %j%==5 GOTO END" means is that the loop will stop when j = 5. It is not how many times the loop gets run. The answer bellow works just fine so just copy and paste that I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::CD "C:\source\"

::only change these three lines
set "start=1"
set "amount=5"
set "length=5"
set "exclude=4,5"

set "excluded=0"
FOR %%G IN (%exclude%) DO (set /a "excluded+=1")
set /a "last=%start%+%amount%+%excluded%"
for /l %%i in (%start%,1,%last%) do (
    set "skip=0"
    FOR %%G IN (%exclude%) DO (if "%%i"=="%%G" set "skip=1")
    if !skip! equ 0 (
    set "folderName=0000000000%%i"
    set "folderName=!folderName:~-%length%!"
    md "!folderName!"
    )
)
```

In this start is the first number, amount is the amount of folder it needs to create, and length is the lenght of the names of the new files, so 1 with length 5 becomes 00001. Exclude is an comma seperated list of all the numbers not allowed

Comment: Yes thanks. Its about 75% of my question answered. Great batch by the way. Is there any way I could exclude creating some folders? e.g set "exclude= 00004, 00005 " I would most probably have to accommodate it in ( set /a "last=%start%+%amount%" )  as in  ( set /a "last=%start%+%amount%+%exclude%" ) do you know of a better way?